# Conditionally render LWC Component in Community Builder in Salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, community-builder, partner-communities

I have a requirement where I have to display the LWC component on record detail page based on record's field value in communities. We can do it in normal Salesforce experience using 'Set Component Visibility' setting in App Builder. But How can we set the same condition in Communities?

When I am trying to add my component thru Community Builder, I don't see any filter criteria in Community Builder where I can specify on what condition the component should render.

Is there any alternative of 'Set Component Visibility' in Community Builder?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?